# How to recover free space after installing ubuntu 12.04

Tags: partitioning

I have a Sony Vaio laptop with 320GB HDD and 3GB RAM. It came with Windows 7. I chose to install Ubuntu 12.04. At the time of installation of ubuntu I did partition as follows.

```
NTFS - 14 GB (Windows 7 Recovery)
NTFS - 140 MB (Windows 7 Loader)
Swap area - 1.5 GB
EXT4 - 162 GB (/)
Free Space - 142 GB
```

Now after installation it only shows 149 GB of free space inside `/home`. How do I recover the free space of 142 GB? And how do I allocate it? Do I have to reinstall the OS if I need to recover it?

Comment: you don't need to reinstall ubuntu.Just take a screenshot of gparted and then upload it to imgur.com.Atlast provide the uploaded link here.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to reinstall Ubuntu. Simply use `gparted` to allocate the free space.

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Fire it up with

```
gksudo gparted
```

and reallocate the free space as desired.

Answer (score 0):

if you can run a live session - i.e from the installation media you used, you can resize you partitions from there using either Disk Utility or GParted to recover your free space.

Otherwise, you can't resize a partition while it is still mounted.

Good luck and keep us updated.